# How do I stop this div's width from decreasing?

Tags: html, css, scroll, resize, overflow

I have an HTML `table` inside of a `div`. I would like the div's width to be able to decrease dynamically without any of its contents being wrapped and without the height increasing. Instead, I would just like to have a horizontal scroll bar, and no vertical scroll bar.

[Here is my JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/s9pbzqy1/4/) (Please don't mind the messy HTML - it was generated using ASP .NET MVC Razor).

You can see by my CSS that I tried using `overflow-x: scroll` on the outer div, but it didn't quite do the trick.

Please let me know how I can stop the div's contents from resizing. Thanks.

EDIT: The contents of the `table` inside the `div` are dynamic, so hard coded widths won't work here.

Comment: Looks like Adam who provided the wrong answer deleted his response and downvoted my topic... but thanks to @diegorp and Pangloss for your solution.

Comment: We don't know who down voted your question. But i'm not surprised - SO suggests "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**." You also accepted an answer with exactly the same solution that posted at a later time, which sounds quite inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Pangloss, I'll keep that in mind for next time. And thanks again for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you don't want the content of the table to be wrapped so you can use something like this:

```
#container table * {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And I think you don't need `overflow-x: scroll;` you can use `overflow-x: auto;` and overflow will only appear when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to prevent text wrapping.

```
#container {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gusx05v/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your CSS:

```
#container {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Change the `350px` to whatever you'd like.  The `overflow-y: hidden;` line removes the vertical scroll bar and the `max-width` line sets the upper limit on the element's width.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately I can't use any hard coded width values. See my response to Adam's answer.

Comment: No @AdamBuchananSmith, the width is completely dynamic, so no hard coded values will work for me. Please see [Pangloss's solution](http://jsfiddle.net/1gusx05v/)